# Find the angle between the planes formed by two faces on a tetrahedron.

Tags: geometry

Given the tetrahedron OABC with $$BC=10, \ \ AC=8, \ \ \sin\angle ACB=\frac{3}{4}, \ \ OA=4, \ \ \triangle ABC\equiv \triangle OBC.$$

$\hspace{1cm}$[image: Diagram of the tetrahedron]

If $\theta$ is the angle formed by the plane $ABC$ and the plane $OBC$, I have to find $\cos\theta$, $\sin\theta$ and then the volume of the tetrahedron.

I was asked to find the area and the height of the triangle $ABC$ (which are 30 and 6). But haven't found a way to know the value of $\cos\theta$.

My try was: Using the net of the tetrahedron all I have to find is the angle $\angle ABO$. From $\sin\angle ACB=\frac{3}{4}$ we know that $\cos\angle ACB=\frac{\sqrt{7}}{4}$, then by the cosine rule $AB=2\sqrt{41-10\sqrt{7}}$. I planed to use this value on the triangle $OBA$ since $AB=OB$, but using again the cosine law I end up with something really far from the real answer

> $cos\theta=\frac{7}{9}$

Then I have to find the volume of the tetrahedron and I already have the area of the base (triangle $ABC$) but still don't see clearly how to measure the height of the tetrahedron.

Comment: $\theta$ is by definition the angle formed by the altitudes $AH$ and $OH$ of triangles $ABC$ and $OBC$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. If $M$ is the middle of $OA$, then $OM$ is perpendicular to the triangle $MBC$, and hence the volume of $OABC$ is equal to:
$$
\mathrm{vol}(OABC)=\frac{1}{3}OA\cdot \mathrm{Area}(MBC)
$$